# How to select a value with MySQL based on another table's value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in my database. One called: `points` and another called: `sample`.

The `points` table looks like the following:

```
id  user_id     points
1   5           200
2   7           400
3   8           7000
4   12          900
5   23          3100
```

The `sample` table looks like the following:

```
id   points     number
1    500        10
2    1000       20
3    3000       30
4    5000       40
5    10000      50
```

I would like to select for example `user_id = 12` and determine which `number` (from the sample table) belongs to his points. the dertermination should be based on their points. If they didn't reach a higher number in the `sample` table, they should receive the `number` before that.

However it is not vital for my case. I would only want to know how can I select from the first table using a sample table looking for values, when there is no predefinied table connection beween them? I just want to select from the first table based on some conditions of the second table's values.

How is it achievable?

Comment: what is your desired result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get the value for only 1 row you can use `MAX`, as done by hellcode, or you can use `LIMIT`

```
SELECT s.number
FROM   points p
       INNER JOIN sample s ON s.`points` <= p.`points`
WHERE  user_id = 12
ORDER BY s.number DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

to get the `number` for all the `user_id` you need a subquery

```
SELECT p.user_id
     , (SELECT s.number
        FROM   sample s 
        WHERE  s.`points` <= p.`points`
        ORDER BY s.number DESC
        LIMIT 1) Number
FROM   points p
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7553e/8)</kbd> with both the queries

If the user as less then the minimum point value `NULL` is returned

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(s.number)
 FROM points AS p, sample AS s
 WHERE p.user_id = 12
 AND p.points >= s.points
```

And maybe you should add a row with 0 points and 0 number in your sample table to get a result for less than 500 Points.